# getblocktemplate times out after being called many times

Tags: json-rpc

I am writing a program about bitcoin mining. It calls the RPC method `getblocktemplate` every second. Sometimes bitcoind doesn't reply to my RPC getblocktemplate request, but bitcoind still accepted new transactions and downloaded new blocks, but RPC calls didn't work.

I checked the CPU and memory usage; both are fine. I am sure it is not the problem of my computer system, because I tried connecting to some other bitcoind. At first, they worked fine, but after running a long time, this problem would come again.

I did not find a good way to solve it. When the RPC request does not reply, I've tried restarting bitcoind, and then it worked again. My bitcoind version is 0.9.3. Any ideas?